# Why number of rows being inserted in MySQL is less when inserted using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to insert data from text file into MySQL using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command.

When I hit this command in MySQL window I get the total number of records inserted.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filepath' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

However, when I pass the same command using ruby, I see the less data is getting inserted.

```
connect.query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filepath' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t';")
```

I have verified by printing the above query and it is the same.

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3 version 6.3.10 build 12092614

Answer (score 0):

If 'filepath' is a variable, is will not be expanded. Try this:

```
connect.query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '#{filepath}' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t';")
```

If 'filepath' is a file path literal, try using an absolute path from the root. That is, if MySQL is running locally.

If this query is being submitted to a remote MySQL server, then there is no hope of it opening a local file, and you may need to rethink your import strategy completely.

Comment: Yes, filepath is a literal which holds my file location and I am using absolute path as you have mentioned.
Here, the problem is being the same query that is being used, why we are getting two different results.
When I execute that query directly in mysql, I can see that total number of rows are being inserted.
But, if I pass the same through Ruby, I can see some data loss.

Comment: Are SOME records being imported when going through Ruby? If so, then you need to pare the problem down and identify what is different between those rows. Perhaps some have unicode characters? Once you identify what is different about the missing rows, you'll probably have a big clue.  Possibly character encoding settings?